# remove space at top while coping html table data to any text documents

Tags: html, css

I know its a very silly problem but unable to get rid of it I am generating a dynamic table via ajax and what i want i will copy the html table data to notepad and upload those data via another application but the problem is when i try to copy the html table data it is adding an extra space at top of the notepad,but i don't want any space at top to complete my another task .

I am not good at html, css that much  so I have added the generated table data below, if you copy the data and paste to notepad you will find a space at top .I want to remove it. I tried many online solutions but those didn't help.So help required Thanks.

```html
<html><head>
    
</head>
    <body cz-shortcut-listen="true">
        
        <div>
            <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" class="reportTbl" border="0" align="center" style="float:left">
                <tbody>
    <tr><td>358929090221233</td><td>*DN</td></tr>
    <tr><td>358929090222454</td><td>*DN</td></tr>
    <tr><td>358929090233592</td><td>*DN</td></tr>
    <tr><td>358929090233691</td><td>*DN</td></tr>
    <tr><td>358929090233717</td><td>*DN</td></tr>
    <tr><td>358929090233758</td><td>*DN</td></tr>
    <tr><td>358929090233774</td><td>*DN</td></tr>
    <tr><td>358929090233790</td><td>*DN</td></tr>
    <tr><td>358929090233832</td><td>*DN</td></tr>
    <tr><td>358929090233873</td><td>*DN</td></tr>
    <tr><td>358929090233899</td><td>*DN</td></tr>
    <tr><td>358929090233931</td><td>*DN</td></tr>
    <tr><td>358929090233972</td><td>*DN</td></tr>
    <tr><td>358929090233998</td><td>*DN</td></tr>
    <tr><td>358929090234038</td><td>*DN</td></tr>
    <tr><td>358929090234095</td><td>*DN</td></tr>
    <tr><td>358929090234111</td><td>*DN</td></tr>
    <tr><td>358929090234533</td><td>*DN</td></tr>
    <tr><td>358929090262930</td><td>*DN</td></tr>
    <tr><td>358929090263516</td><td>*DN</td></tr>
    </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>

    





</body></html>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing a line break character between `<div>` and `<table>` like this:

```html
<html><head>
    
</head>
    <body cz-shortcut-listen="true">
      <div><table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" class="reportTbl" border="0" align="center" style="float:left">
      <tbody>
        <tr><td>358929090221233</td><td>*DN</td></tr>
        <tr><td>358929090222454</td><td>*DN</td></tr>
        <tr><td>358929090233592</td><td>*DN</td></tr>
        <tr><td>358929090233691</td><td>*DN</td></tr>
        <tr><td>358929090233717</td><td>*DN</td></tr>
        <tr><td>358929090233758</td><td>*DN</td></tr>
        <tr><td>358929090233774</td><td>*DN</td></tr>
        <tr><td>358929090233790</td><td>*DN</td></tr>
        <tr><td>358929090233832</td><td>*DN</td></tr>
        <tr><td>358929090233873</td><td>*DN</td></tr>
        <tr><td>358929090233899</td><td>*DN</td></tr>
        <tr><td>358929090233931</td><td>*DN</td></tr>
        <tr><td>358929090233972</td><td>*DN</td></tr>
        <tr><td>358929090233998</td><td>*DN</td></tr>
        <tr><td>358929090234038</td><td>*DN</td></tr>
        <tr><td>358929090234095</td><td>*DN</td></tr>
        <tr><td>358929090234111</td><td>*DN</td></tr>
        <tr><td>358929090234533</td><td>*DN</td></tr>
        <tr><td>358929090262930</td><td>*DN</td></tr>
        <tr><td>358929090263516</td><td>*DN</td></tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

</body></html>
```

Comment: oky but I added a div before but same result happens ,is the div in html code taking space ?? i don't understand ,but yours answer it seems fine

Comment: Sorry I can't explain this situation but in my experience the line break is always existing even browsers don't read them. So it will be copied to other editors.